# Filter elements of a JSON by their subelements' contents in Windows shell using JQ?

Tags: json, jq

This may be asked elsewhere but I have trouble finding a similar case:

Trying to filter the Tor network's relay consensus (https://onionoo.torproject.org/details) based on whether a relay is "Running" and if it has a "Fast" flag or not in order to make another json made up of the selected relays. Possibly even a more concise version that only lists certain elements of each relay (nickname, fingerprint, etc).

I'm trying to use this in a batch script, which makes JQ difficult to work with as it requires hoops to jump through in order to make it work with Windows' shell.

Looking through the Tutorial and manual, I'm stumped. Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.  It's OK to reference the entire file of interest, but it would be helpful (both for potential responders and future readers) to see a *minimal* but complete example on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filter will select relays with `Running` and `Fast` flags and yield an array of objects containing only `nickname` and `fingerprint` fields, tweak it to meet your requirements.

```
.relays | map(select(.flags | index("Running") and index("Fast")) | { nickname, fingerprint })
```